# What is the difference between GenerateDocument and TemplateApply[NotebookTemplate[

Tags: functions, bugs, evaluation, templates

**Bug introduced in V10.0 and persisting through V10.4**

**Since V10.3** the bug still remains but additionally the `Genarate` and `GenerateDocument` examples, previously working correctly, are now exhibiting a new [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) described in: [**What has changed in the Template system in 10.3?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97292/5478)

#### The problem

`GenerateDocument[ _NotebookObject ]` seems to do the same what `TemplateApply[
 NotebookTemplate @ _NotebookObject ]` does except that the latter evaluates more than it should. It does not respect "leave unevaluated" cell properties.

---

#### Example

Let's create a `File -> New -> Template Notebook` and fill it with the following template:

```
TemplateExpression[ "test: " <> TemplateSlot["tag", DefaultValue -> "DEFAULT"]]
```

[image]

created using available `DockedCells'` buttons `Slot/Expression`. The `Cell Behaviour` is set to `Leave Unevaluated`.

---

`Generate` test gives me anticipated:

[image]

the same result I get with

```
GenerateDocument[
 Notebooks[][[2]]  (*this template was 2nd on my Notebooks[] list*)
]
```

**But**

```
TemplateApply[
 NotebookTemplate @ Notebooks[][[2]]
]
```

Gives correct notebook but evaluates the cell printing

> "test: DEFAULT"

The same is the case when I add parameters like `<|"tag" -> "test2134"|>` to those functions.

---

#### Question

Behaviour of `TemplateApply` is unexpected to me.

Why this evaluation happens? Have I missed something in documentation?

---

I don't see any reason why that cell is evaluated. And I don't see how my opinion may change with small update of docs like suggested by support:

> I have not heard back from the developers for the question yet. It looks like that
>
> ```
> TemplateApply[NotebookObject[...]]
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> TemplateApply[NotebookTemplate[NotebookObject[...]]]
> ```
>
> returns different results, and yet in the documentation this is not mentioned.
>
> I have filed a suggestion for adding the clarification of this issue. Thank you very much for giving us feedback and hopefully this issue would be improved in future release.'

That's why I'm adding [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).