# What has changed in the Template system in 10.3?

Tags: functions, bugs, templates

**Bug introduced in 10.3 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

There are couple of issues that are breaking my code after upgrading to 10.3.

I wasn't able to narrow all of them down but this is what I've found. Somethings is going wrong with evaluation:

[image]

Let's put `TemplateSlot` inside `TemplateExpression`, like above, give to the former a default value and try to generate an example. In 10.2 and 10.3:

[image]

gives:

[image]

Have I missed something? Which one is expected result? I'd say 10.2 works as expected.
Is this the case on Mac and Linux too?

---

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3522351] was created.

Comment: Looks like `TemplateExpression` is not working right in 10.3 ... Too bad we did not get a chance to beta-test before releasing this version.

Comment: @Kuba Would you share the official response (three workdays have certainly elapsed...) to the support case -- or at least give the gist of it?

Comment: @gwr Bug is confirmed but the workaround is offtopic in my opinion :) but I will edit it later, maybe I've missed something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed with V11.0.0 release.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be an incompatible change to NotebookExpression.
While I don't quite know how to fix your example, I went ahead and fixed my trouble, i.e. just some input cells which have to be evaluated and hidden.
This can be achieved with the following button:

```
   Button["TemplateExpression Exorcist",
  Module[{cell},
   (* move from inside the cell to the visible cell bracket *)
   Do[SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell], {10}];
   cell = (NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]] /. 
       Cell[BoxData[
          FormBox[TemplateBox[boxes_, 
            "NotebookTemplateExpression"], _]]] :> boxes ) //. 
     BoxData[{b_, "General", BoxData}] :> BoxData[b];
   NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], cell]]] // CreatePalette
```

So a cell like this one (whichi works in a template in 10.2)

```
Cell[BoxData[Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"myreport", "[", 
         RowBox[{
           Cell[
            BoxData[
             FormBox[
              TemplateBox[{"\"var\"", "\"t0\"", "Named", BoxData}, "NotebookTemplateSlot"], 
              TextForm]]], ",", "\"novar\""}], "]"}], " "}],"General",BoxData},
    "NotebookTemplateExpression"], TextForm]]]], "Input",
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     BoxData[
      TemplateBox[{"EvaluateDeleteInput"}, "NotebookTemplateCellBehavior"]]], None}, {None, None}}]
```

is change to a working one (in 10.3)

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"myreport", "[", 
   RowBox[{Cell[BoxData[
     FormBox[
      TemplateBox[{"\"var\"","\"t0\"","Named",BoxData},
       "NotebookTemplateSlot"], TextForm]]], ",", "\"\<novar\>\""}], "]"}], " "}]], "Input",
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[
     BoxData[
      TemplateBox[{"EvaluateDeleteInput"}, "NotebookTemplateCellBehavior"]]], None}, {None, None}}]
```